# How to add a multidimensional dataframe to another multidimensional dataframe as a union?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframes:

The MAIN dataframe A:

```
   A  B
0  1  0
1  1  0
```

The second dataframe B:

```
   A  B
0  0  1
1  1  0
```

The third dataframe C:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  0  0
1  0  1  1
2  0  0  1
```

In python pandas, I want to add A,B and Cthem in such a way that the structure of the resulting dataframe D consists of same  columns and rows structure as the MAIN dataframe A while the the values of rows/columns are added.

A + B + C

```
   A  B 
0  2  1 
1  2  1
```

And by Union addition, I mean that if values > 1, make it 1. So the final
A + B + C is:

```
   A  B 
0  1  1 
1  1  1
```

As you can see, the structure of first A dataframe is maintained while the values from common rows and columns are added. The common rows and columns are variable so I need a code to do this automatically by detecting common rows and columns. Any ideas how to do this?

**UPDATE**

Please note that the data frames can multidimensional:
For example:

A

```
      A  B 
0  a  2  1 
1  a  2  1
```

C

```
      A  B  C
0  a  1  0  0
0  b  1  0  0
0  b  1  0  0
1  a  0  1  1
2  c  0  0  1
```

In this case I am expecting: A + C to be:

```
      A  B 
0  a  3  1 
1  a  2  2
```

Thereby keeping the structure of MAIN dataframe A. Then 'binarized' to

```
      A  B 
0  a  1  1 
1  a  1  1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending a bit on how much of your given structure will generalize,

```
In [50]: df_a | df_b | df_c.loc[df_a.index, df_a.columns]
Out[50]:
   A  B
0  1  1
1  1  1
```

Comment: That's clever !

Comment: @MaxU: Thanks. Is there a better way of slicing one dataframe by the contents of another than `.loc[df.index, df.columns]`? Feels a bit hacky.

Comment: It looks quite OK to me. We can also do `df_c.lookup(df_a.index, df_a.columns)`, but i'm not sure it's better compared to your solution

Comment: Do you think this will work with Multidimentional dataframes? @MaxU

Comment: @Elisha512, please provide a reproducible sample data set and your desired data set. Then we could easily test our solutions...

Comment: Well, this particular one won't since the dataframes now contain values different from 0 and 1, meaning that the bitwise or operation no longer suffices. You could still combine it with MaxU's suggestion below and do something like `(df_a + df_c.loc[df_a.index, df_a.columns]).ne(0).astype(np.int8)` though.

Comment: @fuglede the dataframes are still supposed to contain values 0 and 1. I added the values to explain it better

Comment: In that case, that is if both `df_a` and `df_c` contain only zeros and ones, then `df_a | df_c.loc[df_a.index, df_a.columns]` solves the multiindex case as well. (As I suppose you can verify on your own data as well?)

Answer (score 3):

IIUC:

```
In [56]: (d1 + d2 + d3).dropna(how='all').dropna(axis=1, how='all').ne(0).astype(np.int8)
Out[56]:
   A  B
0  1  1
1  1  1
```

**UPDATE:**

```
In [129]: idx = A.index.intersection(C.index)

In [131]: (A.loc[idx] | B.loc[idx, A.columns]).gt(0).astype('int8')
Out[131]:
     A  B
0 a  1  1
1 a  1  1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
((dfA+dfB+dfC).reindex(index=dfA.index,columns=dfA.columns)>=1).astype(int)
Out[252]: 
   A  B
0  1  1
1  1  1
```

Updated :

```
(A+C).reindex(A.index,columns=A.columns)
Out[297]: 
       A    B
0 a  3.0  1.0
1 a  2.0  2.0
```

Comment: do you think it will still work if the DFs are multimentional?

Comment: @Elisha512 *multimentional* can you explain it ? from you sample data , this should work

Comment: please check out my UPDATE in question

Comment: @Elisha512  your mutiple index structure... you have duplicated key ? , which will make most of the method can not work as normal . I delete one line  0  b  1  0  0 then reindex still work for u